# Adding a key only to a hash based on an if statement

Tags: ruby, refactoring

Typically, we define a hash as

```
h={:a=>val1, :b=>val2}
```

However, i want to add a condition to only add in the key :b if val2 is not a nil value. Something like

```
h={:a=>val1}
h[:b]=val2 if val2
```

But can it be encapsulated in a single line?

Comment: I don't see any good reason to do this on a single line, unless your monitor is half an inch tall.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
h = { :a => val1 }.merge(val2 ? { :b => val2 } : {})
```

But don't do this. Just keep it simple.

Answer (score 4):

```
h[:b] = val unless val.nil?
```

Comment: I guess my point was that it is stupid to worry about doing it in a single line.  Who cares?  Worry about real problems.

Answer (score 4):

You don't have to worry about nil elements in hash, because you can simply clean up hash from them:

```
{:a => 1, :b => nil}.reject { |k, v| v.nil? } # {:a => 1}
```

Comment: But it appears that the OP wanted [:a] in there even if its value was nil.

Answer (score 2):

as of ruby 2.4, you can use [Hash#compact](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.4.0/Hash.html#method-i-compact)

```
h = { a: 1, b: false, c: nil }
h.compact     #=> { a: 1, b: false }
h             #=> { a: 1, b: false, c: nil }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could override the []= operator for just that one hash, or make a subclass of Hash and override it there.

```
hash = {}

class << hash
  def []=(key, value)
    case key
    when :b
      raise StandardError("Invalid :b value") if value.nil?
    end

    super(key,value)
  end
end

hash[:a] = 10
hash[:b] = nil  # Will raise exception
```

Comment: this is too complex for now, but would be great for future projects with such a need , thanks!